# How to make a CSS menu from raw HTML code

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML code of a menu, I have started creating the CSS for the menu but I have come to a halt as I am not sure where to go next

I have added this CSS so far:

```
#menu-my-integra, ul.sub-menu {
    list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#menu-my-integra li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right:10px;
}
ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
}
#menu-my-integra li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

So, this shows the menu in a horizontal position but I want to display the sub menus in a vertical list below the parent item.

I [created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odzqj7r5/1/) here:

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out there on this, here is one http://code-tricks.com/simple-css-drop-down-menu/

Comment: thank you for that, ive used that CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/odzqj7r5/3/) which works well. however i cannot work out how i can make the sub menu's have the same width and each link on the sub menu to have the same width

Comment: I wrote a book series titled "Functional CSS" and the last case of the first volume covers (in great detail) how to build a multi-level dropdown menu.  It's a cool case that also uses flexbox and media queries.  Cheers.

Comment: ive changed my code to this now: http://jsfiddle.net/odzqj7r5/6/ how can i make the hover actions work on the a too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by implementing the box-sizing:border-box attribute:

```
/*Initialize*/
ul#menu-my-integra, ul#menu-my-integra ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu-my-integra li, ul#menu-my-integra ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
    background: #666;
    text-align:center;
}
/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu-my-integra li a, ul#menu-my-integra li ul.sub-menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#menu-my-integra li {
    position: relative;
}
/*sub menu*/
ul#menu-my-integra li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#menu-my-integra li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
```

NOTE: you will have to adjust the % width of the 'li' elements depending on how many there are. Hope that helps!